# Update List Box with outputs from file name select from another class Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

```
#___________________________________________________________
def open_files(self):


    file_name_list = []
    FM_file_name_list = []
    RG_file_name_list = []

    path = easygui.fileopenbox(multiple=True)

    #print(path)

    for i in range(len(path)):


        file_name_list.append(path[i])


        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(path[i])


        #print (file_extension)

        if file_extension == '.FDV':

            FM_file_name_list.append(os.path.basename(path[i]))

        if file_extension == '.R':

            RG_file_name_list.append(os.path.basename(path[i]))
```

class GraphPage(tk.Frame):

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    self.controller=controller

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


    self.FM_List_Box =tk.Listbox(self)
    self.FM_List_Box.config(highlightbackground='steelblue', highlightthickness = 1)
    self.FM_List_Box.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y, padx = 5)
```

I'm trying to get the values within the list 'FM_file_name_list' into the list box 'self.FM_List_Box'. The method 'open_files' is contained within the menu bar of the application in a different class, so the list box has been initially created before it is run.

It would be greatly appreciated if some could help me understand how you can update the values of a list box from a method in a different class.

Comment: That would depend on what you named the classes and how they are layed out. Show us a [mcve] that we can run and test.

Comment: use first_class as argument in second_class - `__init__(self, parent, controller, first_class):` - and then you have access to elements from other class. Or you can directly put this list as argument - `__init__(self, parent, controller, some_list):`. BTW you have to use `self.` in `self.FM_file_name_list` to have access outside function .

Comment: or create in `GraphPage` method which updates listbox and use it in `open_files` - other_class.update_listbox(FM_file_name_list)`

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively simple.

You simply need to call the `class`'s variable from the other class.

This can be done something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

class OtherClass:
    def __init__(self):
        OtherClass.list = ["1", "2", "3"]

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.root)
        self.listbox.pack()
        for i in OtherClass.list:
            self.listbox.insert(END, i)

OtherClass()
root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

So here we have a `class` `OtherClass` which contains a `list` `OtherClass.list`. We can then access this `list` from our `App` `class` by calling `OtherClass.list`.

If you run the program you will see that we are successfully able to pull the `list` from one `class` to the other.